# How do I fetch firebase storage video url to video player?

Tags: firebase, flutter, video, firebase-storage

I'm trying to make an app that have an upload video file (like youtube form when want to upload a video).And I want to add a video player for preview or thumbnail but when I tried with firebase storage url from upload a video from camera or file it doesn't work but when I put the video url value manually from firebase storage it works.(the pick & upload to firebase works)

Video Player code:

```
VideoPlayerController? _controller;
Future<void>? _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
String? videoUrl;

@override
void dispose() {
// TODO: implement dispose
_controller!.dispose();
super.dispose();
}

@override
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
getUserData();
_controller = VideoPlayerController.network("$videoUrl");
_initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller!.initialize();
_controller!.setLooping(true);
_controller!.setVolume(1.0);
}
```

Pick Video & Upload to Firebase:

```
Future _pickVideo(ImageSource source) async {
final pickedFile =
    await _picker.pickVideo(source: source,);
if(pickedFile == null){
  return;
}

await _uploadVideoFile(pickedFile.path);
}

Future _uploadVideoFile(String path) async {
final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
    .ref()
    .child('videos')
    .child('${DateTime.now().toIso8601String() + p.basename(path)}');

final result = await ref.putFile(File(path));
final fileUrl = await result.ref.getDownloadURL();

setState(() {
  videoUrl = fileUrl;
});
}
```

Video Preview:

```
FutureBuilder(
                  future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
                  builder: (context, snapshot){
                    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
                      return AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: _controller!.value.aspectRatio,
                      child: VideoPlayer(_controller!),);
                    } else {
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the value that you get manually from firebase storage with the value that you set here final fileUrl = await result.ref.getDownloadURL();

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: fileUrl = await result.ref.getDownloadURL(); this is the value that you get when you upload the video. It is an URL link, now see the link that you manually copy and paste from firebase and if they are different you probably need some permissions( research on that).